# Trouble Iteratively Parsing several XML results into PHP

Tags: php, xml, ncbi

I am trying to write a PHP script to take advantage of the E-utilities service at NCBI (national center for biotechnology information).

I can supply a url with a search term ("alaS" in this example) and retrieve the XML result with no problem, with code such as:

```
<?php
$startUrl="http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=gene&term=alaS&retmax=10000&usehistory=y";

$xml1=simplexml_load_file($startUrl) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml1->IdList->children() as $child1)
   {
$newUrl1="http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=gene&db=protein&id=" . $child1;
echo $newUrl1 . "<br>";
   };
?>
```

This works fine (the result can be observed at http://djcamenares.x10.mx/testing/parse1.php

However, when I try to get the resulting links and have the script retrieve their results, I get nothing. This is the following code:

```
<?php
$startUrl="http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=gene&term=alaS&retmax=10000&usehistory=y";

$xml1=simplexml_load_file($startUrl) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$geneIDa=array();

foreach ($xml1->IdList->children() as $child1)
   {
$newUrl1="http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=gene&db=protein&id=" . $child1;
array_push($geneIDa, $newUrl1);
   };

foreach ($geneIDa as $x1)
{
$xml2=simplexml_load_file($x1) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo $xml2->LinkSet->LinkSetDb[1]->Link->Id . "<br>";
};
?>
```

That is available at http://djcamenares.x10.mx/testing/parse3.php

Any suggestions? Maybe a better way I should structure my overall program? I need to pass variables / results to back and forth to this utilities server 3 times (Once to search for gene IDs, then to link each gene ID with a protein ID, and finally to retrieve protein sequence).

Thanks for any and all help; sorry if this question is redundant or already answered; I'm relatively new to PHP.